# Calculation of distinct and sum

Tags: sql

I have a a below table where all the columns are same except for group column and I am calculating count(distinct group) and blocks in the same table:

Input:

| id | time | CODE | group | value | total_blocks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 32206 | mn2 | 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 22 | 32206 | mn4 | 1 | 200 |

Output:

| id | time | CODE | group | value | count(distinct group) | blocks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 32206 | mn2 | 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 22 | 32206 | mn4 | 1 | 2 | 100 |

count(distinct group) is just distinct values (mn2 and mn4) and blocks overall wrt to code(32206) is 200, but I am splitting the same over the two rows.
The output should look exactly the same in the final, without removal of any columns.

I tried using count(distinct) but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide both sample input and expected outcome as tables in your question, don't add images or links. Read also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and tag your DBMS.

Comment: Sure, added the format.

Comment: you have bad data design. Your total blocks that spans over each row.... hmmmm

Comment: will using row_number with partition work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Oracle***:
Try it like here:

```sql
WITH    -- S a m p l e    d a t a
    tbl (ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_GROUP, A_VALUE, TOTAL_BLOCKS) AS
        (
            Select 1, 22, 32206, 'mn2', 1,  200 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 22, 32206, 'mn4', 1,  200 From Dual   
        )


-- S Q L --
Select 
    ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_GROUP, A_VALUE, 
  Count(DISTINCT A_GROUP) OVER(Partition By CODE) "COUNT_DIST_GROUP", -- Count distinct groups per CODE
--  Count(DISTINCT A_GROUP) OVER() "COUNT_DIST_GROUP",    --Count distinct groups over the whole table
  TOTAL_BLOCKS / Count(*) OVER(Partition By CODE) "BLOCKS"  -- TOTAL_BLOCKS divided by number of rows per CODDE
-- TOTAL_BLOCKS / Count(*) OVER() "BLOCKS"  -- TOTAL_BLOCKS divided by number of rows in the whole table
From 
    tbl

R e s u l t :
        ID     A_TIME       CODE A_GROUP    A_VALUE COUNT_DIST_GROUP     BLOCKS
---------- ---------- ---------- ------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
         1         22      32206 mn2              1                2        100 
         1         22      32206 mn4              1                2        100
```

Comments in code explain the basic use of Count() Over() analytic function.  More about analytic functions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174).

Using just **ROW_NUMBER**() analytic function and **Max**() aggregate function...

```sql
-- S Q L --
Select
  r.ID, r.A_TIME, r.CODE, t.A_GROUP, r.A_VALUE, MAX_RN "COUNT_DIST_GROUP", (TOTAL_BLOCKS / MAX_RN) "BLOCKS" 
From
    (   SELECT    ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_VALUE,  Max(RN) "MAX_RN"
        FROM     (Select  ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_VALUE, Row_Number() OVER(Partition By CODE Order By CODE, A_GROUP) "RN"
                  From    tbl ) 
        GROUP BY ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_VALUE  ) r
Inner Join tbl t ON(t.CODE = r.CODE)

        ID     A_TIME       CODE A_GROUP    A_VALUE COUNT_DIST_GROUP     BLOCKS
---------- ---------- ---------- ------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
         1         22      32206 mn2              1                2        100 
         1         22      32206 mn4              1                2        100
```

... and it works with another group of similar data:

```sql
WITH    -- S a m p l e    d a t a
    tbl (ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_GROUP, A_VALUE, TOTAL_BLOCKS) AS
        (
            Select 1, 22, 32206, 'mn2', 1,  200 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 22, 32206, 'mn4', 1,  200 From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 1, 22, 32207, 'mn6', 1,  450 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 22, 32207, 'mn7', 1,  450 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 22, 32207, 'mn8', 1,  450 From Dual 
        )
-- S Q L --
Select
  r.ID, r.A_TIME, r.CODE, t.A_GROUP, r.A_VALUE, MAX_RN "COUNT_DIST_GROUP", (TOTAL_BLOCKS / MAX_RN) "BLOCKS" 
From
    (   SELECT    ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_VALUE,  Max(RN) "MAX_RN"
        FROM     (Select  ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_VALUE, Row_Number() OVER(Partition By CODE Order By CODE, A_GROUP) "RN"
                  From    tbl ) 
        GROUP BY ID, A_TIME, CODE, A_VALUE  ) r
Inner Join tbl t ON(t.CODE = r.CODE)

        ID     A_TIME       CODE A_GROUP    A_VALUE COUNT_DIST_GROUP     BLOCKS
---------- ---------- ---------- ------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
         1         22      32206 mn2              1                2        100 
         1         22      32206 mn4              1                2        100 
         1         22      32207 mn6              1                3        150 
         1         22      32207 mn7              1                3        150 
         1         22      32207 mn8              1                3        150
```

Comment: why is it giving different result when we use row_number()

Comment: @Tanmay If you use row_number over all you will get 1 and  2 and if you partition it by group then 1 and 1.. You want 2 and 2 as count of distinct groups.if partition is by code then again 1 and 2.

Comment: okay, count with over is not working in redshift sql editor.

Comment: @Tanmay This is Oracle and I use Oracle SQL Developer....Try to put row_number instead of count. Make this a subquery and in the outer sql select max of that row_number and do the grouping by all other cols

Comment: is there any other option other than count() over, because I am bound to use row_number or dense_rank and both gave wrong results, and writing everything in redshift, which doesn't support count over()

Comment: @Tanmay as in my last comment. Put rownumber in this code. Then select max(thar row number) from (the whole that code) and group by the rest selected cols. Do the math in outer query. I'm not at computer now. Writing on mob... The subquery should be inside brackets...

Comment: Yes, i did try that. But we won't get max , we get both 1 and 2 because we will grouping even A_GROUP and we need A_GROUP finally in our query as one of the columns.

Comment: If you can wait 30 mins, I will try to think it over...

Comment: Sure, it can wait.

Comment: @Tanmay Here you are - had to use another outer query...